# matplotlib: add median in a box plot

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, boxplot, median

I am using the following code to create a box plot:

```
df.assign(index=df.groupby('category').cumcount()).pivot('index','category','days') \
    .plot(kind='box', sym='bD',ax=axes[0,0], ylim = [0,150], rot = 90)
```

[image]

I am wondering is it possible to add the median value in the same plot (using for example red circle)? Thanks!

Comment: The green line inside the boxes is the median. Is the question how to replace the green line by a red circle?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest:  No, the green line is mean, not median. I want both mean and median in the graph. Thanks!

Comment: As said, the green line is the median, at least if you did not change anything outside of the code you show (which is no [mcve]). So the question is now how to show the mean as well?! This would be answered e.g. in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29777017/show-mean-in-the-box-plot-in-python), using `showmeans=True`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: Thanks! Would it be possible to specify the symbol of means? (Couldn't find it in another question)