# How to add mean into boxplot visualization?

Tags: python, seaborn, boxplot

I was able to visualize my data in a boxplot using Seaborn.

```
sns.boxplot( x=df['Score'].astype('float'), y=df['Group'] )
```

The visualization shows me: all four quartiles, lower and upper whisker, and some outliers. How can I also add the Mean line into the boxplots? See current visualization (without mean).

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show mean in the box plot in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29777017/show-mean-in-the-box-plot-in-python)

Answer (score 26):

I just figured it out. The code works like this:

```
sns.boxplot(x=df['Score'].astype('float'), y=df['Group'],showmeans=True )
```

Comment: i find more elegant if you throw ```meanline=True``` into the mix, that is, inside `sns.boxplot(...`.

Comment: Note: `showmeans` is a _matplotlib_ argument.